# How to get DataFrame indices for multiple rows configurations using Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the DataFrame `P1` and `P2`:

```
P1 =
   A  B
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1

P2 = 
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  1  0  1
6  1  1  0
7  1  1  1
```

I would like to know if there is a concise and efficient way of getting the indices in `P1` for the row (tuple/configurations/assignments) of columns `['A','B']` in `P2`.
That is, given `P2['A','B']`:

```
P2['A','B'] = 
   A  B
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  0  1
3  0  1
4  1  0
5  1  0
6  1  1
7  1  1
```

I would like to get `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`, since the first and second rows in `P2['A','B']` corresponds to the first row in `P1`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` and extract the overlapping keys

```
In [3]: tmp = p2[['A', 'B']].merge(p1.reset_index())

In [4]: tmp
Out[4]:
   A  B  index
0  0  0      0
1  0  0      0
2  0  1      1
3  0  1      1
4  1  0      2
5  1  0      2
6  1  1      3
7  1  1      3
```

Get the values.

```
In [5]: tmp['index'].values
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

However, there could be a native NumPy method to do this aswell.

Comment: Perfect, @JohnGalt! By curiosity, how would be the NumPy method? Thanks.